# Is there a way to change selenium/node-chrome image chromedriver.exe version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am running Selenium-hub and Selenium node chrome on Docker containers and I need to change the version of the chromedriver wihtout affecting the image version.
That is, imagine I am using `selenium-hub: image: selenium/hub:3.3.1-cesium` and `selenium-chrome: image: selenium/node-chrome:3.3.1-cesium` but I want to update the chromedriver version to `2.41`, without affecting the docker image version.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that there is no way to do this with selenium/node-chrome image. 
Why ? because this image belongs to selenium. You cannot change the image that you are not the owner.

But you can create your own image based on selenium/node-chrome. Simply just run a selenium/node-chrome container with name *node_chrome_container*, you can change chromedriver to the version you want inside that container and then commit it to your own image.

> docker commit -m "Added custom image" node_chrome_container DOCKER_HUB_USER/custom-node-chrome:latest

I will be on your local PC. You should also push that image to docker hub under your repository.

> docker push DOCKER_HUB_USER/custom-node-chrome

link reference here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-docker-image-and-push-it-to-docker-hub/